# Does my own prompt window stops javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new at javascript. I want to make a javascript function to wait until a user input. I know I can use prompt but the window does not look good, so I want to make my own prompt window. I search and found that I can do it using jquery ui or by simply creating my window using html+css+javascript, but my question is: If i create my own prompt window does the function waits until the input is given? Or does it simply calls a function after the input is given?

This is basically what I want to do:

```
function () 
{
   var input = MyPrompt(); //Wait here for a user input, like a c scanf

   //Rest of the function who will use the input given

}
```

I really need that the javascript function stops executing, like a scanf or a prompt would do. Because most of the solutions I found simply call a function after you click the "confirm" button

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide code for MyPrompt? If you're using the default browser prompts, like `prompt()`, `alert()`, or `confirm()`, then yes you would be blocking JS execution

Comment: Yes, I know if I use alert(), promp() or confirm() it stops JS execution, but I want to create a MyPrompt() function wich would do the same, but have a much nicer GUI, the problem is all the solution I saw online does not stop the JS execution, but call a new function once a button is pressed

Comment: Just use a `setInterval()` to check if your prompt is over in your code. While it's not, just don't call anything else.

Comment: As far as I know, there is __no__ way of pausing the execution of the JS like how `prompt()` and `alert()` do. The only choices you have are to use an interval to wait until the input value has been set, or just use callbacks.

Comment: I do not have a MyPrompt() function because the only way I was able to really stop the execution of the JS function was by calling the default prompt() function

Comment: By adding an event handler to your button, i.e. handleButtonClick, in which you process the user's data, you should not be blocking the event loop. Do you have any other questions?

Comment: this can block the event loop: `while(true){ console.log() }` (please don't do it in your browser lol)

Comment: @varbrad, but the setInterval will simply check if the variable was set or not, by calling another function over and over, but it wont stop the function execution, I really need to stop the function execution...

Comment: @JulianSoro I want to use it in a browser, so I cannot use while loops...

Comment: The short answer is no, and the slightly longer answer is that you shouldn't try to replicate the blocking behavior of these browser functions.  Use a more modern way to deal with the asynchronicity like Promises.  If you are only targeting new environments or use a transpiler you can jump straight to async/await which will give you blocking-like syntax.

Comment: it was a joke because someone said "As far as I know, there is no way of pausing the execution of the JS". You DON'T want to create an infinite loop for no reason

Comment: In that case there really isn't a way to halt JS execution in the manner you are looking for. @JulianSoro 

Comment: As @NoahFreitas mentioned, the use of Promises is likely what you are going for. The remaining code in your function (after the MyPrompt() call) can be executed upon promise resolve. And if MyPrompt() isn't necessary, then you can resolve the promise immediately giving the impression it wasn't deferred at all.

Answer (score 2):

By the nature of JavaScript there is no way to "pause" an execution of a javascript application. Thats why in JavaScript most external call handlers (like url calls or file system operations in NodeJS) are implemented as callbacks.

EcmaScript spec creators are trying to provide `async/await` [features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), but in fact this is just a syntactic sugar for [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Your best bet is to create your own "prompt" or use any of already existing [like this](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and put what you want to do after getting user input as a "callback" to that prompt:

```
showMyPrompt({
  success: function(value){ console.log('User said ', value); },
  close: function(){ //handle pressing of a "cancel" button if needed }
})
```

and in your dialog function:

```
function showMyPrompt(params){
  // show your prompt here
  $('.dialog-ok-button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = $('.my-prompt-input').val();
    params.success && typeof params.success == 'function' && params.success(val);
  });

  // and do similar for "cancel" 
}
```

Comment: Yes, but has I said before I want a function that will stop execution like prompt() and display a message, not a function who will call another function after user give the input

Answer (score 1):

A simple [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) based solution might look like this. 
 Notice that your original function is written the same way--aside from the addition of `async` and `await`.

```js
function MyPrompt() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let dialog = document.createElement('dialog');
        dialog.innerHTML = `
            <form>
                <input type="text" required>
                <button type"submit">Ok</button>
            </form>
        `;
        document.body.appendChild(dialog);
        dialog.showModal();
        dialog.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            dialog.remove();
            resolve(dialog.querySelector('input').value);
        });
    });
}

(async function ()
{
   var input = await MyPrompt(); //Wait here for a user input, like a c scanf

   console.log(input);
   //Rest of the function who will use the input given

}());
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you have to turn the function who call MyPrompt() into an async function, and I do not want that. 

But Thanks ;)